# Show a total value from a something that is referenced in other tables

Tags: sql, database

I'm sorry if the question is confusing, but hopefully it makes sense once I explain it.

[image: Example]

In the table "t_land" I have all the pieces of land I have with all the properties, and the two other tables "t_plantland" and "t_grassland" in which plants or animals grow respectively. I want to have a query which tells me what is the total amount of land used for each of those types of lands.

I hope it makes sense, cause this is difficult to explain for me. Thank you.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Comment: The desired results is to see the TOTAL AMOUNT OF LAND USED for each of the land types. For example. If there are 3 pieces of land used by t_plantland, one having 3 hectars, the other 6, and the third 7, i want a query that shows what is the total.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a lot simpler like below

```
Select * from (
          ( SELECT sum(size) AS Plant_Tamt from 
         t_land 
       where land_id in (select 
          land_id from t_plantland)
           )
         JOIN
           (SELECT   sum(size) AS Grass_Tamt from t_land 
           where land_id in 
          (select land_id from t_grassland)
           )
           )
```

Comment: Yes, This is a lot simpler and it actually came back with more accurate results, because in the grassland table, some of the land ids were referenced multiple times so it kinda added those too :D Thank you, dude!

Comment: See the updated now you see the desired amt for each type seperately

Comment: The updated one has a syntax error: 
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 418
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'JOIN'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 419
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: can you please check now

Answer (score 0):

Well, a `join` comes to mind:

```
select sum(case when pl.landid is null and gl.landid is not null then l.area end) as grassland_area,
       sum(case when pl.landid is not null and gl.landid is null then l.area end) as plantland_area,
       sum(case when pl.landid is not null and gl.landid is not null then l.area end) as both_area,
       sum(case when pl.landid is null and gl.landid is null then l.area end) as neither_area       
from land l left join
     plantland pl
     on pl.landid = l.landid left join
     grassland gl
     on gl.landid = l.landid;
```

Comment: `... when pl.landid is not null and pl.landid is null then ...` - shouldn't it be `gl.landid is null`?

Comment: That's something in the right direction. Thanks a lot my dude!